# Relocate the 'cancel reply' link of the Wordpress comment reply form

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have styled the Wordpress "reply" form different then the main "comment" form.

I want to remove the 'comment-reply-title' ("Leave a reply") from the "reply" form. I've succeeded doing this with `display: none`. Unfortunately, the "cancel reply" link is in the same `div` of the 'comment-reply-title', so that link is also being removed.

I've searched the internet for a solution to move the "cancel reply" link outside this div to another position; in my case I want to put it next to the default "Reply" link; or if this is NOT possible, next to the submit button.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery.

Add this before the closing `</body>` tag in the *footer.php* template:

```
<script>
jQuery( function( $ ){
    $( '.comment-reply-link', '.comment-body' ).on( 'click', function(){
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
    } );

    $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
        $( this ).hide();
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Then use the Customizer to add this custom CSS: ([click here if you need help](http://dinevthemes.com/custom-css-wordpress-customizer/))

```
.reply #cancel-comment-reply-link:before {
    /* This will print a middle-dot character with leading spaces. */
    content: ' \00B7\0020';
}
```

(You could also add the code right into the *style.css* file of your theme.)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this using hooks instead of jQuery. The following will add the cancel button to the end of the form.

```
// Remove the comment reply button from it's default location
function my_remove_comment_reply_link($link) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('cancel_comment_reply_link', 'ndic_remove_comment_reply_link', 10);

// Add the comment reply button to the end of the comment form.
// Remove the my_remove_comment_reply_link filter first so that it will actually output something.
function my_after_comment_form($post_id) {
    remove_filter('cancel_comment_reply_link', 'ndic_remove_comment_reply_link', 10);
    cancel_comment_reply_link('Cancel reply');
}
add_action('comment_form', 'my_after_comment_form', 99);
```

Comment: For anyone trying this out, I'm not sure where the 'ndic_remove_comment_reply_link' part came from, but this should actually be 'my_remove_comment_reply_link'. Changing this worked for me with everything else kept the same.